# Дсесериализация части объекта как subobject

Tags: c#, .net, json

Допустим есть некий `json` объект, и мне не нравится расположение полей в нем:

```js
{
    "title": "Игра престолов",
    "title_en": "Game of Thrones",
    "year": 2011,
    "tagline": "Победа или смерть",
    "description": "К концу подходит время благоденствия, и лето, длившееся почти десятилетие, угасает. Вокруг средоточия власти Семи королевств, Железного трона, зреет заговор, и в это непростое время король решает искать поддержки у друга юности Эддарда Старка. В мире, где все — от короля до наемника — рвутся к власти, плетут интриги и готовы вонзить нож в спину, есть место и благородству, состраданию и любви. Между тем, никто не замечает пробуждение тьмы из легенд далеко на Севере — и лишь Стена защищает живых к югу от нее.",
    "poster_url": "https://st.kp.yandex.net/images/film_iphone/iphone360_464963.jpg",
    "duration": 55,
    "countries": ["США", "Великобритания"],
    "genres": ["фэнтези", "боевик", "драма"],
    "kinopoisk_rating": 9,
    "kinopoisk_votes": 268732,
    "imdb_rating": 9.4,
    "imdb_votes": 1553335,
    "premiere_ru": "2011-09-08",
    "premiere_world": "2011-04-17",
    "actors": ["Питер Динклэйдж", "Лина Хиди", "Эмилия Кларк", "Кит Харингтон", "Софи Тёрнер", "Мэйси Уильямс", "Николай Костер-Вальдау", "Иэн Глен", "Алфи Аллен", "Джон Брэдли"],
    "directors": [ "Дэвид Наттер", "Алан Тейлор", "Алекс Грейвз"],
    "producers": ["Дэвид Бениофф", "Д.Б. Уайсс", "Джордж Р.Р. Мартин"],
    "writers": [ "Дэвид Бениофф", "Джордж Р.Р. Мартин", "Д.Б. Уайсс"],
    "composers": ["Рамин Джавади"],
    "editors": ["Кэти Вейланд", "Фрэнсис Паркер", "Криспин Грин"],
    "designers": ["Дебора Райли", "Джемма Джексон", "Филип Элтон"],
    "operators": ["Анетт Хаелльмигк", "Джонатан Фриман", "Роберт МакЛаклен"]
}
```

Мне не нравится то, что рейтинг, даты выхода и заголовки, находятся прямо в этом объекте, я хочу их вынести в отдельный интерфейс/класс.

Объявляю 3 подтипа интерфейсов:

```
// Заголовки
public interface ITitle
{
    string Russian { get; }
    string English { get; }
}

// Рейтинг
public interface IRating
{
    float Rating { get; }
    ulong VotesCount { get; }
}

// Премьеры
public interface IPremiere
{
    ref DateTimeOffset Russia { get; }
    ref DateTimeOffset World { get; }
}
```

В итоге получаю некий скомплектованный интерфейс:

```
public interface IData
{
    ITitle Title { get; }
    uint Year { get; }
    string Tagline { get; }
    string Description { get; }
    Uri PosterUri { get; }
    ushort Duration { get; }
    IRating KinopoiskRating { get; }
    IRating ImDbRating { get; }
    IPremiere Premiere { get; }
    IList<string> Countries { get; }
    IList<string> Genres { get; }
    IList<string> Actors { get; }
    IList<string> Directors { get; }
    IList<string> Producers { get; }
    IList<string> Writers { get; }
    IList<string> Composers { get; }
    IList<string> Editors { get; }
    IList<string> Designers { get; }
    IList<string> Operators { get; }
}
```

Вроде бы все не плохо, однако, мне теперь не понятно как мне сделать такой объект класса, что бы `json` десериализатор понял что куда класть.

Как можно решить такой вопрос?

---

Все что мне пришло на ум, это такая реализация:

```
internal class Data : IData
{
    #region Properties

    [JsonIgnore] public ITitle Title { get; }
    [JsonProperty("year")] public uint Year { get; }
    [JsonProperty("tagline")] public string Tagline { get; }
    [JsonProperty("description")] public string Description { get; }
    [JsonProperty("poser_url")] public Uri PosterUri { get; }
    [JsonProperty("duration")] public ushort Duration { get; }
    [JsonIgnore] public IRating KinopoiskRating { get; }
    [JsonIgnore] public IRating ImDbRating { get; }
    [JsonIgnore] public IPremiere Premiere { get; }
    [JsonProperty("countries")] public IList<string> Countries { get; }
    [JsonProperty("genres")] public IList<string> Genres { get; }
    [JsonProperty("actors")] public IList<string> Actors { get; }
    [JsonProperty("directors")] public IList<string> Directors { get; }
    [JsonProperty("producers")] public IList<string> Producers { get; }
    [JsonProperty("writers")] public IList<string> Writers { get; }
    [JsonProperty("composers")] public IList<string> Composers { get; }
    [JsonProperty("editors")] public IList<string> Editors { get; }
    [JsonProperty("designers")] public IList<string> Designers { get; }
    [JsonProperty("operators")] public IList<string> Operators { get; }

    #region SubObject data

    #region Title

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    internal string TitleRu
    {
        get { return Title.Russian; }
        set { ((Title) Title).Russian = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty("title_en")]
    internal string TitleEn
    {
        get { return Title.English; }
        set { ((Title) Title).English = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Rating

    [JsonProperty("kinipoisk_rating")]
    internal float KpRating
    {
        get { return KinopoiskRating.Value; }
        set { ((Rating) KinopoiskRating).Value = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty("kinipoisk_rating")]
    internal ulong KpVotes
    {
        get { return KinopoiskRating.Votes; }
        set { ((Rating) KinopoiskRating).Votes = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty("imdb_rating")]
    internal float ImdbRating
    {
        get { return ImDbRating.Value; }
        set { ((Rating) ImDbRating).Value = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty("imdb_rating")]
    internal ulong ImdbVotes
    {
        get { return ImDbRating.Votes; }
        set { ((Rating) ImDbRating).Votes = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Premiere

    [JsonProperty("premiere_ru")]
    internal DateTimeOffset PremiereRu
    {
        get { return Premiere.Russia; }
        set { Premiere.Russia = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty("premiere_world")]
    internal DateTimeOffset PremiereWorld
    {
        get { return Premiere.World; }
        set { Premiere.World = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion

    #endregion

    internal MaterialData(uint year, string tagline, string description, Uri posterUri, ushort duration,
        IList<string> countries, IList<string> genres, IList<string> actors, IList<string> directors,
        IList<string> producers, IList<string> writers, IList<string> composers, IList<string> editors,
        IList<string> designers, IList<string> operators, DateTimeOffset premiereRu, DateTimeOffset premiereWorld,
        float kinopoiskRating, ulong kinopoiskVotes, float imdbRating, ulong imdbVotes)
    {
        Title = new Title();
        KinopoiskRating = new Rating();
        ImDbRating = new Rating();
        Premiere = new Premiere();

        Year = year;
        Tagline = tagline;
        Description = description;
        PosterUri = posterUri;
        Duration = duration;
        Countries = countries;
        Genres = genres;
        Actors = actors;
        Directors = directors;
        Producers = producers;
        Writers = writers;
        Composers = composers;
        Editors = editors;
        Designers = designers;
        Operators = operators;
        PremiereRu = premiereRu;
        PremiereWorld = premiereWorld;
        ImdbRating = imdbRating;
        ImdbVotes = imdbVotes;
        KpRating = kinopoiskRating;
        KpVotes = kinopoiskVotes;
    }
}
```

Comment: я бы сделал (грубо говоря в конечном итоге) 2 Объекта: класс как я хочу юзать в коде, и класс как у меня лежит где-то (как в вашем JSON)...и в Nuget есть такая штука как [мапер](https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper/) - он преобразовывет один объект в другой по какому-то конфигу. ТАкой подход зачастую используют для реализации многослойной архитектуры доступа к БД (В c# entity => DTO)

Comment: Объект к сожалению не один, и держать 2 объекта в памяти будет неуместно.

Comment: 2 Никто не заставляет...он просто нужен для вычитки с места хранения. Чтобы мапер понял что он получил, и во что ему это нужно сделать...по большомуц счеты вы тоже самое делаете, просто другим способом